# Image url from CK editor not working on multiple pages

Tags: php, mysql, ckeditor

I have content from a CK editor inserted into my database. 
I use this content both in the page itself (for the user) and on the backend page where the admin can change it.

However the CMS files are in a different folder (root/CMS) while the content pages are in root. The path to my image will only work on one of the pages.

This is my url to the image:

```
<img alt="test" src="../images/content/testing.jpg" style="height:200px; width:200px" /><
```

Because of the source (../) it will only work on the admin page. Is there a way for me to also show it on the regular content page without moving files from the folders?

Comment: try to use path like this "/images/content/testing.jpg" if images folder is on root

Comment: Hmm I tested it and that would be a solution. However I currently can't work from the root, since the original website is on the root. When the new site will be moved it will work so I guess I can't fix the problem now. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: For this you can add folder name before /images/, when you want to go live you can remove this. like  "/development/images/content/testing.jpg" if images folder for development is also in development folder else first comment if good to go

Answer (score 1):

If you add base path before the img src url, I hope its will working fine for all pages.

You can set your base path as you need, simply define additional resource types in the configuration file (config.php / config.cfm / config.asp / config.ascx, depending on your version of CKFinder)

EX: type.Url = BaseUrl + "images/";

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you images folder is on root then try to use this

```
<img alt="test" src="/images/content/testing.jpg" style="height:200px; width:200px" />
```

Or get your URL like this and use it with image path

```
<?php
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])){
$protocol = ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != "off") ? "https://" : "http://";
}
else{
$protocol = 'http://';
}
$url = $protocol . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
?>
```

If you are in development folder then add folder name

```
$url = $protocol . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/development";
<img alt="test" src="<?php echo $url;?>/images/content/testing.jpg" style="height:200px; width:200px" />
```